# stack trace after segmentation violation very slow

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault

I'm developing a piece of python/C++ software relying on a whole bunch of libraries.
I work on linux, using gcc to compile and run my software from the terminal.
The software is a C++ library for which I generate bindings for python using ROOT/cling, and which I use from python.

Recently (and without any reason that I am aware of), printing the stack traces after a segmentation fault has become extremely slow, which is of course hampering the debugging quite a bit.
The first issue is that I only have a very vague understanding of what is happening in the background when a stack trace is compiled.
But even then, I have a hard time believing that compiling the stack trace can take several minutes.
What are ways in which I can understand what is happening, and potentially debug this behavior?

Comment: At a guess you are low on memory or your library is very large

Comment: The library is very large, but my memory usage never exceeds 15%.

Comment: Ironically, attach a debugger to the code when it is printing the stack trace and see what it is doing? I would not be surprised if it is calling `addr2line` over and over on a large binary.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks. I'll do it and report back :-)

Comment: What are you using to print the stack trace? Is your system going to swap?